# How to check windows update server whether is in use in company?

Tags: windows, windows-update

Some computers are unknown, however configuration exist in firewall, after change window update server's ip, how to know whether it is in use?

How to verify windows update server working in company's network?

Answer (score 0):

Which Version?

On the Client you can have a look at `C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log` to see if the client is getting an answer from your WSUS.
Also you can manually force a client to contact WSUS `wuauclt /detectnow` and `wuauclt /reportnow`. If only the server IP changed and this machine has a corresponding DNS entry you should have no issues.